# Tranforming multi value dictionary keys to list

Tags: python, dictionary, key

My input is a dictionary with values such as:
{0: '205,3', 1: '0,110,18,49,8', 10: '11,73'}
Unfortunately the values of the dictionary as you can see are strings ''.
My expected outcome is some like this
[(0,205),(0,3),(1,0),(1,110),(1,18).....]
My code is the following.

```
def generate_edges(newDict):                                   
    edges = []
    for node in newDict:
        for neighbour in newDict[node]:
            if neighbour == ',':
                continue
            else:
                edges.append((node, int(neighbour)))
    print(edges)
    return edges
```

The problem is that as you can see, the number denoted as values a cut digit by digit with an outcome of:
[(0,2),(0,0),(0,5),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,1),(1,0).....]
How can i circumvent this problem and get the values as whole numbers instead of one digit numbers?

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: What happened to `hfg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` and create a `defaultdict(list)`.

As told in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

> When each key is encountered for the first time, it is not already in the mapping; so an entry is automatically created using the `default_factory` function which returns an empty list. The `list.append()` operation then attaches the value to the new list.

So you can easily construct the dictionary that you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict


l = [(2009, 'abc'), (2010, 'dfg'), (2009, 'hfg'), (2011, 'kdi')]

result = defaultdict(list)

for pair in l:
    result[pair[0]].append(pair[1])

print(result)  # {2009: ['abc', 'hfg'], 2010: ['dfg'], 2011: ['kdi']}
```

You simply iterate over each *tuple* in your list and append it's values to the dictionary.

If you want to get rid of the `[]` within each value, you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
...

def join_lists(d: dict, sep: str=', ') -> dict:
    return {key: sep.join(values) for key, values in d.items()}

print(join_lists(result_dict))  # {2009: 'abc, hfg', 2010: 'dfg', 2011: 'kdi'}
```

I implemented a function called `join_lists()`, which accepts a dictionary as a first parameter and an optional separator as a second (which defaults to `", "`). The functions returns a *new* dict, which has the same keys, but it's values are comma-separated.

Comment: exactly, this is the output i get, but when i want to print that i still have the [' '] in each value!
How can i get rid f that?

Comment: @GeorgeKladis I edited my answer with a possible solution of your format problem.

Comment: Thanks man you rock! Exactly the format i needed! As a question for your code what does operator -> do and also how is it possible this new function (join_lists) takes as argument the result_dict without calling the function in which it is used?

Comment: @GeorgeKladis `->` is simly a **function annotation**. It describes each function parameter's *type* (I used it because the function params become self-explanatory. It says: the `join_lists` function accepts two parameters: `d`, which is a `dict`, and an optional one `sep`, which is a `str`. The function returns a value of type `dict`). Oh, this with `result_dict` in the function is my silly mistake. I didn't see it because it was all in one file and that's why it worked. I will edit my answer immediately. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you just want the very first value for the key, key being the year

so this should do it

```
result = dict()
for year, value in your_list:
    if year not in result:
    result[year] = value
```

this will of course drop the later occurrence of the second item in the tuple. I do not see you specifying what you want to do with it